# Google Cloud devappserver

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

Since the new update of 427.0.0 when I run the command:
`python2 /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --max_module_instances="default:1" --dev_appserver_log_level=info --enable_host_checking=false --automatic_restart=no --runtime_python_path="$(pwd)/lenv/bin/python3.11" --port=8080 --support_datastore_emulator=yes  --default_gcs_bucket_name=x --datastore_emulator_port=8081 "$(pwd)"`
In order to test locally using dev_appserver.py with legacy bundled services in python3. I get the error:

ERROR: Python 2 is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK. Please use Python version 3.5 and up.

If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.

Reverting the version to the previous one did not work. If I set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON env variable by using
`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` the same error still stands (I did source the bashrc afterwards and it exists in env).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[427.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#breaking_changes) has the following under 'Breaking Changes'

> (Google Cloud CLI) Deprecated Python 2. The minimum supported Python version is Python 3.5.

This means you now have to run it with Python 3. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/tools/local-devserver-command?tab=python#set_up_the_local_development_server_tool) says

> Regardless of your app's runtime or language version, you must run dev_appserver.py **with Python 3** and set the **CLOUDSDK_DEVAPPSERVER_PYTHO**N environment variable in your shell to the path of your Python 2 interpreter.

This means you now run it with

`python3 CLOUD_SDK_ROOT/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

If you're running versions **426.0.0 or lower**, then you have to use

`python CLOUD_SDK_ROOT/bin/dev_appserver.py --runtime_python_path=/usr/bin/python3 app.yaml`

or

`python CLOUD_SDK_ROOT/bin/dev_appserver.py --runtime_python_path="python27=/usr/bin/python2.7,python3=/usr/bin/python3" app.yaml]`

where `python` refers to your python 2 installation

Comment: I got it working! Your solution didn't work at first as the .py file was throwing an error (although this got me past the versioning issue). I ended up re-downloading the google-sdk and now with your python3 command it works. FWIW - I'm on Apple M2. Guessing google's 'components update' didn't actually update everything properly so re-download was needed.